# How do I set up central place for ssh public keys for several workstations?

Tags: ssh, key, public, sharing

Our setup is a working place with several workstations, laptops and a NAS (for storing workproducts and backups).

To access other workstations directly we use ssh with the usual keygen and copying each others public key in the .ssh directory.

But changing the ssh key on one machine results in several copy actions to all other workstations.

Is there an easy to maintain way to store the public keys e.g. on the NAS an tell ssh to look there for them not in in the local .ssh directory.

Or is a key server needed to share these keys?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It would not be an very good idea to do that as you have some security issues, [Central location for authorized keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/313465/is-a-central-location-for-authorized-keys-a-good-idea) details issues faced with this kind of configuration settings.

Comment: I'm almost sure you meant to link to [this ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/313465/is-a-central-location-for-authorized-keys-a-good-idea) question?

Comment: Your right, another user could overwrite the public key and get access. So is there a simple key server to share those key and update them (or just hold them so every workstation can update keys if needed)